# How can I set a class to the first Item in array by default and remove it and apply to another item on click?

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-class

In Angular you can use ngClass to conditionally apply your class like so.

```
<div
    *ngFor="let group of step.groups; let firstItem = first;"
    class="layout--stepper__subgroup"
    ngClass]="{'is-active': group.prop === activeProp}"
    (click)="scrollToSection(group)">
    p class="t-data">{{group.header}}</p>
</div>

scrollToSection(group) {
    this.activeProp = group.prop;
    let scroll = document.querySelector(`#${group.prop}`).scrollIntoView();
}
```

Now whenever I click the item in my list the class `is-active` will be applied to that specific list item. However, what if I want to apply `is-active` to the first item on the list by default?

If I change my code to be:

```
ngClass]="{'is-active': group.prop === activeProp || firstItem}"
```

Now both the first item on the list and the item clicked will both have the `is-active` class. How can I set the first item on the list to have the `is-active` class by default and then remove it when I click another item on the list?

Comment: If you don't want to change to much code `ngClass]="{'is-active': group.prop === activeProp || (firstItem && activeProp===undefined )}"` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aware of the value of `prop` for your `firstItem`, the easiest way to do it would be to set `activeProp` initially to that value.

In case the value is not known to you, try setting `is-active` to your `firstItem` only if `activeProp` is not defined which would be when no item is selected.

```
[ngClass]="{'is-active': group.prop === activeProp || (firstItem && !activeProp)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the activeProp as the prop of the first group of the groups array:

```
if(this.step.groups.length > 0)
    this.activeProp = this.step.groups[0].prop;
```

And your first condition:

```
[ngClass]="{'is-active': group.prop === activeProp}"
```

will run smoothly.

Comment: I have several arrays where I need to do the same thing. How can I modify this code to do it on multiple arrays?